# Does PHP have job control like bash does?

Tags: php, multithreading, job-control

does PHP support something like ampersand in bash (forking)? Let's say I wanted to use cURL on 2 web pages concurrently, so script doesn't have to wait before first cURL command finnishes, how could one achieve that in PHP? Something like this in bash:

```
 curl www.google.com &
 curl www.yahoo.com &
 wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does PHP support something like ampersand in bash (forking)?**
<s>No.</s> See the other answers, though I do point out that the PCNTL extension is UNIX only.

**...how could one achieve that in PHP?***
[cURL supports running multiple downloads concurrently](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-add-handle.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`popen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) to open a process and let it run in the background, but there's no language support for background operations like there is for `bash` (which was made to run tasks, anyways; PHP was made for scripting stuff).

Using proc_open, you can then use [`proc_get_status`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php) to know when the processes are terminated. I'm afraid there's no `wait` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can write asynchronous methods if you really want to, but it's a lot of work, and probably a terrible design idea if you're using PHP.

Comment: How can you write asynchronous methods with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of queuing mechanism is often preferable.  Gearman is an open source queuing mechanism you can use.  I also have a blog post on the Zend Server Job Queue that talks about running tasks asynchronously [Do you queue? Introduction to the Zend Server Job Queue](http://www.eschrade.com/page/queue-introduction-zend-server-queue-4b8eef5c).

You could also use something like the Zend Framework Queuing classes to implement some of the asynchronous work.  [Zend_Queue](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.queue.html)